# Transfering MMS messes up group chats

Tags: backup, restore, mms

I've tried three different tools, "My Backup Pro", "Easy Backup & Restore", and the backup/restore feature of "GO SMS Pro" to transfer my texts from one Android phone to a new one.

Regardless of what I use, after I've restored the backup to the new phone, all the restored messages within a group chat have been split up:

When I go to a group thread, it *only* shows the messages *I* sent. And the group chat texts *other* people sent get erroneously placed in the *individual* chat threads instead of the group chat.

Not sure if it matters, but the old phone is Android 4.1.2, and the new one is 5.1.1. Both are Samsung.

How can I transfer group chats without them getting messed up?

UPDATE: I tried using "Titanium Backup" but the results were...weird. When I use that, then "GO SMS Pro" finally *reads* the data correctly, BUT it can no longer send/receive texts at all and Android's built-in messaging app will immediately crash every time I try to run it. This is getting REALLY frustrating, nothing is working for what should be a trivial, basic function.

UPDATE 2: Found Samsung's "Smart Switch" app which worked corectly.